# What is the replacement for menu_link_load()?

Tags: 8, navigation

Drupal 7 has [menu_link_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_link_load/7.x) to load a single menu item. What is the Drupal 8 equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

Drupal 8 menu links are now content entities. The equivalent to loading a D7 menu link object would be loading a [`MenuLinkContent` entity](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21menu_link_content%21src%21Entity%21MenuLinkContent.php/class/MenuLinkContent/9.0.x). This can be done via the static `Drupal\menu_link_content\Entity\MenuLinkContent::load()` method.

Comment: I'd add the entity type manager method, too. Because it's pretty generic for any entity type. `\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('menu_link_content')->load($id);`

Answer (score 2):

It should be considered good practice to rely on the **entity type manager** to load entities. First, the pattern is easy to remember and looks the same for any entity type. Just replace `menu_link_content` with `node` or `node_type` or whatever. Second, it supports the dependency injection container to be used in OOP code.

```
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('menu_link_content')->load($id);
```

Read [Working with the Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/working-with-the-entity-api) for more info.

> Avoid using the static `Entity::load()` method in object oriented
> code. Instead use dependency injection to inject the entity type
> manager and load the entity with
> `$this->entityTypeManager->getStorage($entity_type)->load($entity_id)`.
> This ensures that the code is properly decoupled and can be unit
> tested.

Also this issue is a nice read as well: [Node::load($nid) vs. \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($nid)](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2945539)

> Often I hear that
> `\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($nid)` should
> be used instead of `Node::load($nid)`. Is argued that using the later
> is not recommended. I've searched in the relevant doc page, issue or
> change record but none of them could give me a clue why one is the
> preferred way, than the other.